# FIN-PSH-ACK server-side closure provoking RST from the client

Tags: c, linux, http, tcp

I explore client-server interaction and I use nginx server and my own client (c code). when keep-alive request counter is exhausted at the server (nginx's Default: keepalive_requests 100;) I can see in wireshark that the server initiates the closure with [FIN PSH ACK] and the client - I detect the closure by epoll's EPOLLRDHUP | EPOLLHUP flags and call close(file_descriptor) without messing with so_linger whatsoever - will send [RST ACK] packet instead of expected [FIN ACK].

I have impression that this mechanism may be a newer feature that allows a server to initiate closure without having to pass through CLOSE_WAIT phase, but I couldn't find anything relevant off google. Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got my head round it myself. When I call close() based on epoll's RDHUP/HUP flags I do not get 0 from read(file_descriptor) call, that is there is a potential that some data are still in skb (even though I read it before checking RDHUP/HUP flags). Under this circumstances the kernel send RST in place of FIN according to this:

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_termination)

Some host TCP stacks may implement a half-duplex close sequence, as Linux or HP-UX do. If such a host actively closes a connection but still has not read all the incoming data the stack already received from the link, this host sends a RST instead of a FIN (Section 4.2.2.13 in RFC 1122).